# Status Query on US20130163185

Tags: legal-status, us20130163185

In reference to the patent: [US 2013/0163185 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20130163185)

What is the status on the above referenced patent application?

Answer (score 1):

There are several applications in this patent family. Some of the national phase status for the PCT application ([WO 2013/096139 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013096139A1)) can be found via PatentScope:

`European Patent Office 21.07.2014  2012860602`

The European application status can be found at [EP Register](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP12860602):

```
Status: Request for examination was made
Database last updated on 13.11.2015
```

And the US application status can be found in the Image File Wrapper at [USPTO Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) (direct links are not possible, so search by *Publication Number* for **US 20130163185 A1** and open the Image File Wrapper tab:

```
07-16-2015  CTFR    Final Rejection
```

Last paragraphs of the final rejection document:

> THIS ACTION IS MADE FINAL. Applicant is reminded of the extension of
>   time policy as set forth in 37 CFR 1.136(a).
>
> A shortened statutory
>   period for reply to this final action is set to expire THREE MONTHS
>   from the mailing date of this action. In the event a first reply is
>   filed within TWO MONTHS of the mailing date of this final action and
>   the advisory action is not mailed until after the end of the
>   THREE-MONTH shortened statutory period, then the shortened statutory
>   period will expire on the date the advisory action is mailed, and any
>   extension fee pursuant to 37 CFR 1.136(a) will be calculated from the
>   mailing date of the advisory action. In no event, however, will the
>   statutory period for reply expire later than SIX MONTHS from the
>   mailing date of this final action.

Three months would set the expiration of the statutory period for the action at October 16, 2015. Since the date has passed and no response to the action was filed, this application is considered rejected.

If you are interested in the reasons for the rejection, refer to the 15 page Final Rejection document in the Image File Wrapper.